# Put a Vue directive on condition

Tags: vue.js

I want to put a **directive** in a **Vue component** on **condition**.
I have installed a package called "**mask**" and I want to put **v-mask directive** on condition..
in some situations component has no property called "mask" but in some situations has. so I get this error when I don't pass mask to my component
this is the component that I use v-mask directive in :

```
<input v-mask="mask" />
```

is there any way that I could insert v-mask if the mask attribute passed and don't if mask is empty ????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input v-mask="mask" v-if="mask.length">
<input v-else>
```

Comment: thank you very much, is there any way not to duplicate input ?

Comment: it is really based on how the directive is developed. A directive can have a conditional setting but it's up to the developer. In vue, there's no builtin functionality to make it conditional

Answer (score 6):

You could check for the condition before binding the directive.

Consider your use case:

```
<input v-mask="mask" />
```

Your directive would look like this:

```
import { mask } from 'v-mask'

directives: {
    mask: {
      bind(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode) {

        // This is the condition
        if (binding.value) {
          mask(el, binding, vnode, oldVnode)
        }

      }
    },
},
```

The condition in the bind() method checks if the value passed to the directive exists, if it's true-ish.

If it is true-ish, it goes on to execute the actual directive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use computed item here;

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    mask: 'maskdata'
  },
  computed: {
    IsMaskEmpty: function () {
      return this.mask === "";
    }
  }
})
```

after compute a bool result with `IsMaskEmpty` function, you can create DOM element as you want with this condition.

```
<input v-mask="mask" v-if="!IsMaskEmpty">
<input v-if="IsMaskEmpty">
```

Comment: thank you very much, is there any way not to duplicate input ?

Comment: If you want to add/remove an attribute on input you can create your own input component for mask.

Comment: However when you use v-if on your code if the condition return false there wont be generate any DOM element on the browser. This means you will only dublicate inputs on code, one of them will never render.